# How can we handle uncaught exceptions in CLI/Worker Spring Boot apps?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

Does Spring (in particular, Spring Boot) provide any functionality for handling uncaught exceptions in CLI/Worker apps (e.g. not Spring MVC, Spring REST, and other types of apps that work with HTTP request/respone and/or are deployed to Servlet containers).

For example, I am looking for something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @SomeExceptionHandlingAnnotation
    public void handle(Exception e) {
        // handle e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was a dumb question. Using Spring AOP, we can implement an advice and handle uncaught exceptions there.